# Fill available space without overflowing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a desktop application user interface with html and what i want to achieve is having a fixed header and footer with content filling the remaining (whatever) space the window is. Been trying to use flex but not quite understand how it works with almost all of my trials ending up with an overflow.

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4dxperkp/

```
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  background: tomato;
}

div {
  background: gold;

  height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  background: tomato;
}
```

I also came accross `-webkit-fill-available` but it end up causing an overflow as well.

Comment: What do you want the content to do? You have the main container set to `height: 300px` in your demo.

Comment: Sorry, Why does the old fiddle appear to you ? there is a new one.

Comment: I posted an answer, based on my understanding of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS's **`calc()`** function in `min-height` using javascript (for dynamic height calculations) like:

```
var heightHeader = $('header').height();
var heightFooter = $('footer').height();
var mainHeight = heightHeader + heightFooter;
var divHeight = 'calc(100vh - ' + mainHeight + 'px)';

$('.main-content').css('min-height', divHeight);
```

Have a look at the updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/1604/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: nice but i don't wanna rely on hard coded values (the 96px). Is there any other way ?

Comment: @AhmedTarek Have a look at the updated answer. This might solve your query.

Answer (score 2):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;          /* the container always has full height of the viewport */
}
header {
  background: tomato;
}
div {
  flex: 1;                /* the content div always consumes all free space */
  background: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}
footer {
  margin-top: auto;       /* the footer is always pinned to the bottom */
  background: lightgreen;
  min-height: 60px; 
}

body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<section>
  <header>
    header: sized to content
      <br/>(but is it really?)
  </header>
  <div>
    main content: fills remaining space<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
    x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
  </div>
  <footer>
    footer: fixed height in px
  </footer>
</section>
```